# Function to retrieve closest X & Y in structure?

Tags: c++

**Text file**

```
[0]
total=0

[10000]
total=3
-593 427 683
-976 703 701
-974 307 688

[20000]
total=0

[30000]
total=1
197 -83 153

[30001]
total=1
77 49 244

[40000]
total=0
```

**Header file**

```
using namespace std;

struct LRopeSearch
{
    bool Special;
    int Counter;
    string PN;
    POINT XY;
};

struct LRopeData
{
    int X;
    int Y1;
    int Y2;
};

struct LRData
{
    int LRID;
    vector <LRopeData> Ropes;
};

typedef pair <int, LRData> LRPair;
extern map <int, LRData> LRMap;

void CreateRopeStructure();
```

**Progress**

With my CreateRopeStructure() function, I put all the text file information into the LRopeData structure.

I need a function that would use three integer values; a ID (ex. 10000), a X (ex. -500), & a Y (ex. 400) and using all three integer values, would retrieve based on the ID, the closest X, Y1, & Y2 values.

I have the structure LRopeSearch which can be used in doing so, but I need help beyond this on actually using the structure in a function to retrieve said values.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Also, closest to what? Can you give an example?

Comment: Tip: State your question first, then add the implementation as supplemental information, so readers get to know what to look for faster. Also, what metric should be used for "closest"?

Comment: With the int X and int Y I input into the function, I need for it to find the closest X and Y to the one's I inputted. If I were to input ID = 10000 X = 500 Y = 400, it should give me the following values; -593 427 683

Comment: What formula determines whether one `LRopeData` is closer than another to the input?

Comment: What formula would I use to determine that?

Comment: http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html

Comment: Instead of that, can't I just iterate through each rope within the id and subtract the X by the X input & Y by the Y, and out of all of it, whomever has the lowest value is the one I pick? I do not fully understand your link

Comment: Oh wait. It's 2d only! Yeah. Posting answer in short.

Comment: @user3513035 **[Posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449465/85371)**. Hope that helps. Also **[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/233a23ddd4de3043)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. It took a while to "imagine" what the input data should mean. After your last comment I now understand that the input is several (empty) sets of ropes identified by an ID.

The ropes are finite, vertical, line segments given by (X, Y1)-(X, Y2).

---

I've simplified the data structure, because having the LRID inside LRData was redundant:

```
typedef int                    LRID;
typedef std::vector<LRopeData> LRData;
typedef std::map<LRID, LRData> LRMap;
```

Now assuming you have the data reading implemented (`CreateRopeStructure`), you could just write a brute force search:

```
LRMap CreateRopeStructure();

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LRMap data = CreateRopeStructure();

    // ex. from OP
    int const ID = 10000;
    int const  X =  -500;
    int const  Y =   400;

    // select rope data by ID:
    auto& ropes = data[ID];

    if (ropes.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "infinite" << std::endl;
    } else
    {
        // get the distance to each rope
        std::vector<double> distances(ropes.size());
        std::transform(
                ropes.begin(), ropes.end(), 
                distances.begin(),
                [=](LRopeData const& rope) { return rope.distanceToPoint(X, Y); });
            // for c++03:
            // std::tr1::bind(&LRopeData::distanceToPoint, std::tr1::placeholders::_1, X, Y));

        // print the shortest distance
        std::cout << *std::min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Of course, the most interesting part is: `LRopeData::distanceToPoint`:

```
struct LRopeData {
    int X;
    int Y1;
    int Y2;

    double distanceToPoint(double px, double py) const
    {
        int y1(Y1), y2(Y2);
        // normalize segment endpoints (y1, y2)
        if (y1>y2) std::swap(y1, y2);

        double dx = (px - X);
        double dy = 0;

        if (py<y1)   dy = (py - y1);
        if (py > y2) dy = (py - y2);

        return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/233a23ddd4de3043)** where it prints:

```
96.8401
```

for the query in the OP

#### Full Code Listing

Includes my take on parsing the input:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
//#include <tr1/functional> // bind (for c++03)

struct LRopeData {
    int X;
    int Y1;
    int Y2;

    double distanceToPoint(double px, double py) const
    {
        int y1(Y1), y2(Y2);
        // normalize segment endpoints (y1, y2)
        if (y1>y2) std::swap(y1, y2);

        double dx = (px - X);
        double dy = 0;

        if (py<y1)   dy = (py - y1);
        if (py > y2) dy = (py - y2);

        return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
};

typedef int                    LRID;
typedef std::vector<LRopeData> LRData;
typedef std::map<LRID, LRData> LRMap;
typedef std::pair<LRID, LRData> LRPair;

LRMap CreateRopeStructure();

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LRMap data = CreateRopeStructure();

    // ex. from OP
    int const ID = 10000;
    int const  X =  -500;
    int const  Y =   400;

    // select rope data by ID:
    auto& ropes = data[ID];

    if (ropes.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "infinite" << std::endl;
    } else
    {
        // get the distance to each rope
        std::vector<double> distances(ropes.size());
        std::transform(
                ropes.begin(), ropes.end(), 
                distances.begin(),
                [=](LRopeData const& rope) { return rope.distanceToPoint(X, Y); });
            // for c++03:
            // std::bind(std::mem_fn(&LRopeData::distanceToPoint), std::placeholders::_1, X, Y));

        // print the shortest distance
        std::cout << *std::min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(LRopeData, (int,X)(int,Y1)(int,Y2))

LRMap CreateRopeStructure()
{
    // input
    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    ifs >> std::noskipws;
    typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
    It f(ifs), l;

    // grammar
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    rule<It, LRPair(), blank_type, locals<int> > lrmap;

    lrmap %= '[' >> int_ >> ']' >> +eol
          >> "total" >> '=' >> omit [ int_ [ _a = _1 ] ] >> +eol
          >> repeat(_a) [ int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> +eol ]
          ;

    // parse
    LRMap data;
    assert(phrase_parse(f, l, +lrmap, blank, data));

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    // done
    return data;
}
```

Comment: c++03 version **[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39d775bfb8b1bd0d)** too

Comment: I understand that it represents distance, however, I need it to just put the x and y of the shortest distance rope into integers (understand?).

Comment: @user3513035 You're asking too many things that are just **plain** obvious. I'm **not** using boost. I'm only using it after main, because you didn't show the parsing code :(. You said you already have that part! I made especially clear which includes support what, and even posted a c++03 version. ...

Comment: @user3513035 Of course I understand. I'm sure you should be able to take it from here. Is this homework?

Comment: I think I know how to do this without boost, thank you!

Comment: @user3513035 Oh, well, then, here's the program printing [`Closest rope is at 96.8401, X:-593 Y1:427 Y2:683` using `partial_sort` **live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f2133375f1a315a). Oh, and without boost, obviously (just substitute the parsing). Cheers